how do i confirm my transaction on my trading bot
async def create_and_submit_transfer(sender_keypair: Keypair, swap_transaction: str, sol_client: AsyncClient):
    """
    Submit a signed swap transaction to Solana and confirm it.
    """
    try:
        # Decode the base64-encoded transaction
        try:
            transaction_bytes = base64.b64decode(swap_transaction)
        except binascii.Error as e:
            print(f"Binascii decoding error: {e}")
            return None

        print(f"Decoded transaction length: {len(transaction_bytes)}")

        # Deserialize the transaction
        try:
            transaction = Transaction.deserialize(transaction_bytes)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Transaction deserialization error: {e}")
            return None

        # Sign the transaction with the sender's keypair
        transaction.sign(sender_keypair)

        # Serialize transaction to prepare for submission
        serialized_transaction = transaction.serialize()
        print(f"Serialized Transaction length: {len(serialized_transaction)}")

        # Send transaction and retrieve signature
        tx_response = await sol_client.send_raw_transaction(serialized_transaction, opts=TxOpts(skip_preflight=True))
        tx_signature = tx_response.value  # Retrieve the transaction signature directly

        if tx_signature:
            print(f"Transaction sent with signature: {tx_signature}")

            # Confirm the transaction
            for attempt in range(15):
                confirmation_response = await sol_client.confirm_transaction(tx_signature, commitment=Confirmed)
                if confirmation_response and confirmation_response.value:
                    # Handle confirmation response structure for both list and dict
                    if isinstance(confirmation_response.value, dict):
                        status = confirmation_response.value.get("confirmationStatus", "Unknown")
                    elif isinstance(confirmation_response.value, list) and confirmation_response.value:
                        status = confirmation_response.value[0].get("confirmationStatus", "Unknown")
                    else:
                        status = "Unknown"

                    print(f"Attempt {attempt + 1}: Status - {status}")

                    if status == "finalized":
                        print(f"Transaction confirmed successfully! Signature: {tx_signature}")
                        return tx_signature

                await asyncio.sleep(2 + attempt * 0.5)
            else:
                print("Transaction not confirmed after multiple attempts.")
        else:
            print("Transaction submission failed.")
        return None
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during transaction submission or confirmation: {e}")
        return None


Can you give more details about what happened or didn't happen, and the full stacktrace of any errors you received?
